# Ffmpeg's movflags faststart causes change in size, why?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have used the following command on several mp4 files:

`ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -movflags +faststart -c copy new.mp4`

The resulting files have slightly different sizes than originals, for example one is 8 bytes larger, other one is 1227 bytes smaller, what causes the change in size if supposedly it should only move moov atom to the beginning of the file without altering anything else?

Comment: It's creating a new file, not simply shifting bytes.

Comment: @Gyan Why does it have different size though?

Comment: Because ffmpeg may write boxes that the original does not have or vice-versa.